# How do I style my tree menu's options?

Tags: css

Here is an example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v6kuL/

How do I change Category1, Category2, Category3 to other colors?

HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="/category/category1">Category 1</a>
      <ul class="children">
         <a href="/category/" >
            <li>
         <a href="/category/category1a">Category 1 A</a>
         </li>
         </a>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="/category/category2">Category 2</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="/category/category3">Category 3</a>
      <ul class="children">
         <a href="/category/" >
            <li>
         <a href="/category/category3a">Category 3 A</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="/category/category3b">Category 3 B</a>
         </li>
         </a>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

My attempt is on the jsfiddle linked above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
ul:not(.children) > li > a:first-child {
    color: red;
}
```

<kbd>**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v6kuL/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Create classes with the colors that you want to use, and apply them to the `<a>` tags.

```
<a href="/category/category1" class="red">Category 1</a>
<a href="/category/category1a" class="black">Category 1 A</a>
```

Create a `<style>` tag in your HTML header, and add the classes within the tag.

```
.red{color:red;}
.black{color:black;}
```

In addition to colors like red and black, you can apply any color in RGB format like this: `color: #FFCC00;`

Comment: I edited your response to give a little more info and a slightly better explanation of how to do it.  Feel free to revert if you desire.

Answer (score 0):

I just added this at the beginning of CSS

```
li a{color:red;}
.children a{color:blue;}
```

this way the parent is red and the child is blue. Cheers.